# Samba 4,5 times slower than SCP

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing, scp

I'm getting out of ideas. I am using a RPi2 with ubuntu server 20.04.LTS to serve files with samba.

I'm using ubuntu over the homes laptops but there are some windows and Android phones that are using the samba share to store and browse photos for example.

Actually when I scp from my RPi to my laptop's desktop, I average around 6,5 MBs but when I transfer the same file via Samba (a 130 MB video) from the same directory which is also shared in samba ... I average around 1,5 MBs.

Here is my smb.conf :

```
[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 100
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        dns proxy = no
        map to guest = bad user
        mangled names = no
        dos charset = CP850
        unix charset = UTF-8
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY


[Photos]
        path = /media/photos
        browsable = yes
        writable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        create mask = 777
        directory mask = 777
```

If anyone has an idea ...

To finish, I'd like to apologize about my certainly made english mistakes.

Thanks in advance !